# Xcode iPhone "digest is missing"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, development-environment, organizer

"The digest is missing" in xcode organizer for iPhone 4S.

Anybody knows what this means?

I have used the iPhone for testing/development before without problems, and my other iPhone is working just fine... I formatted the MacBook Pro, and everything else is working fine.

See image:[image: digest is missing]

Comment: Saw this message today for the first time as well. After replugging the phone it worked again.

Comment: Disconnecting the phone and plugging it in again also worked for me.

Comment: Yeah, somehow it worked today, I dont know what I did, but most probably reconnecting it did the job. thanks.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Disconnect the phone/USB from your Mac and reconnected it, restarted Xcode and it worked.

Comment: Wow this worked XD Thanks! I was worried for a minute that i'd have to restore my device..

Comment: Yeah, i know what you mean... got me some sweat on!

Comment: I not even had to restart Xcode. Just reconnecting the device worked. Btw, an iPad.

Comment: This happened to me when plugging in a device with no battery charge. Unplug/replug worked fine without restarting Xcode.

Comment: Thats a good point... i think the phone was uncharged when i plugged it in the first time while xcode was open... Good point :)

Comment: A replug worked for me too. Specifically: (1) Unplug device; (2) Quit Xcode; (3) Launch Xcode; (4) Show Organiser; (5) Replug device. I suspect that this happened for me because this device had not, previously, seen this Mac before. For this reason I had had to 'Trust' it. Perhaps this leaves Xcode, the connection or the device in a muddled state.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thank you.
"Turn it off and on again" - where would we be without stackoverflow?!
:)

Answer (score 2):

I've no reason to doubt the accepted answer, but I thought I'd mention that for me the error message just went away after a while.

This *may* be related to iTunes finishing syncing or Aperture finishing downloading videos from my iPhone, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

It could happen while incompatible `MobileDevice.framework` version. (it happens with beta versions Xcode most recently).

To see which version installed use command:

```
plutil -p /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Resources/Info.plist | grep CFBundleVersion
```

Try to install previous (stable?) version of framework. How to install other version: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24448251/751932).