# Xcode 4.4.1 does not work properly under OSX Mavericks

Tags: xcode, crash, legacy

examples:

1. Organizer shows for iOS 3.1.3 'The digest is missing' key
2. It can crash with next crash data:

UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Extension Xcode.Device.iPhone class 'DVTiPhoneLocator' not found for required key 'locatorclass'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it happens after run *Xcode 6 beta* which install incompatible "MobileDevice.framework" on first launch.

so solution:

1. disconnect any iOS devices, close iTunes, close XCode
2. `sudo rm -rf /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework`
3. start Xcode 5.1.1 - It will install compatible MobileDevice.framework